# Unable to Launch Application through Test application by Robotium

Tags: android-studio, robotium, black-box-testing

I'm trying to write a black box test for android application of which i only have the APK (no source code) using the Robotium. 
I am using android studio 3.1.2. 
Here the code snippet,

```
  import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.robotium.solo.Solo;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public class RobotiumTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

        private static final String 

LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME
            = "com.example.hqsg.activities.HQSoundGuideActivity";

    private static Class launcherActivityClass;
    static {
        try {
            launcherActivityClass = Class
                    .forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }
    }

    public RobotiumTest() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super(launcherActivityClass);

    }

    private Solo mDevice;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mDevice = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mDevice.finishOpenedActivities();
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void test() {
        mDevice.clickOnButton(0);

    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.robotium">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RUN_INSTRUMENTATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

     <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/suman_A/Desktop/key.jks')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.robotium"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testApplicationId 'com.example.hqsg'
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {`enter code here`
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
           enter code here proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    debugImplementation  'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium:5.6.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

**After executing the application I am facing the InitializerError.
Here is the error report,**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:61)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:294)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestsFromTestCase(TestSuite.java:150)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:129)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.NonLeakyTestSuite.<init>(NonLeakyTestSuite.java:33)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestSuite.<init>(AndroidTestSuite.java:46)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidJUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(AndroidJUnit3Builder.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.AndroidRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidRunnerBuilder.java:153)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:73)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:789)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:539)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:382)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.hqsg.activities.HQSoundGuideActivity
at com.example.robotium.RobotiumTest.<clinit>(RobotiumTest.java:25)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.hqsg.activities.HQSoundGuideActivity
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
at com.example.robotium.RobotiumTest.<clinit>(RobotiumTest.java:20)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.hqsg.activities.HQSoundGuideActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hqsg-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.robotium-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.hqsg-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.robotium-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 23 more
```

Tests ran to completion.
Does anyone know anything about this?